# What are the prerequisites for a point-free function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, pointfree

I always thought that the prerequisites for a pointfree function were to get the function arguments to the end of the definition. E.g.

```
-- This can be made pointfree quite easily:    
let lengths x = map length x    
let lengths' = map length

-- However this cannot:
let lengthz x = length `map` x
-- let lengthz' = length `map` (parse error)
```

I originally came across this reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426417/how-do-i-re-write-a-haskell-function-of-two-argument-to-point-free-style). There we have this example:

```
agreeLen :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
agreeLen x y = length $ takeWhile id $ zipWith (==) x y
-- This may look like it can easily be made pointfree, however it cannot
-- agreeLen' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
-- agreeLen' = length $ takeWhile id $ zipWith (==) (zipWith is applied to too few arguments)
```

So why can my first example be made pointfree, but the other two cannot?

Comment: You can make it point free - it just isn't nice `agreeLen = ((length . takeWhile id) .) . zipWith (==)`. http://pointfree.io

Comment: There's no completely precise definition of "pointfree" in Haskell. Usually, using library combinators like `flip, const, id, <*>` and many others is allowed. But that might be considered cheating by some, depending on what you use. I guess `const, <*>` should suffice for everything, as they do allow to define anything in the untyped lambda calculus.

Comment: @chi, eliminators like `bool`, `maybe`, and `foldr` are also generally allowed, as point-free leaves no room for pattern matching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> -- However this cannot:
> let lengthz x = length `map` x
> -- let lengthz' = length `map` (parse error)
> ```

`` \x -> length `map` x `` written point free is simply `map length`. The infix backticks are just syntactical sugar. (As chepner points out, if you really want it you can use a section, i.e. `` (length `map`) ``.)

> ```
> agreeLen :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
> agreeLen x y = length $ takeWhile id $ zipWith (==) x y
> -- This may look like it can easily be made pointfree, however it cannot
> ```

The key word here is "easily". Pretty much anything can be made point-free if you try hard enough. In this case, omitting the `y` parameter is easy if we write `agreeLen` in terms of `(.)` rather than `($)`:

```
agreeLen x y = (length . takeWhile id . zipWith (==) x) y
agreeLen x = length . takeWhile id . zipWith (==) x
```

As for `x`, we can handle it by treating the use of `(.)` to compose `zipWith (==) x` with the other functions as just another case of a value being modified with a function:

```
agreeLen x = (.) (length . takeWhile id) (zipWith (==) x)
agreeLen x = ((length . takeWhile id) .) (zipWith (==) x) -- cosmetical change
agreeLen x = (((length . takeWhile id) .) . zipWith (==)) x
agreeLen = ((length . takeWhile id) .) . zipWith (==)
```

It is not something you'd actually want to do in practice, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: I think not quite anything. You can run into impredicativity with `RankNTypes`.

Answer (score 6):

Your first one *can* be written in point-free style, but you have to adapt it to your use of `map` as an infix function.

```
let lengthz = (length `map`) -- write the partial application as a section
```

The problem with `agreeLen` is that `zipWith` is not a function of one argument, but of two. `zipWith` needs to be applied to both arguments before its result can be passed to `takeWhile id`. The not-easy way to write it in point-free style is

```
-- via http://pointfree.io
agreeLen = ((length . takeWhile id) .) . zipWith (==)
```

Put briefly, `zipWith (==)` is applied to the first argument `x` to `agreeLen` to produce a new function (one that takes a list and returns a zipped list). This new function is given as an argument to `(length . takeWhile id) .`, which produces a new composed function that takes the second argument to `agreeLen` and produce the desired `Int` value.

(@duplode probably [derives this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40918034/1126841) more cleanly than what I was about to attempt.)

A trick that quickly gets out of hand when the initial function takes more than 2 arguments is to explicitly uncurry it, do the composition, then re-curry the result.

```
agreeLen = curry $ length . takeWhile id . (uncurry $ zipWith (==))
```

Answer (score 4):

> I always thought that the prerequisites for a pointfree function were to get the function arguments to the end of the definition

Well, as other answers have shown, this isn't a necessary condition; almost anything can be made point free. So it's not a prerequisite as such, rather just *one* simple rule for rewriting a function definition. This particular rule even has a name: **eta reduction** (as in the Greek letter η, spelled out in English as "eta"). But it's not the only such rule.

The conditions for applying eta reduction are also not quite just "get the arguments to the end". That's a loose description of what it "looks like" when you can apply eta reduction, but the actual condition isn't one you can just apply blindly to the source code text without considering the structure of the expression.<sup>1</sup>

The *real* rule is to look for something like:

func x = expr x

By that I do *not* mean "some text (that I'm calling `expr`) followed by `x`", but rather "some well-formed expression (that I'm calling `expr`) **applied to** `x`". The distinction is that I'm talking about the structure of the expression, not the order of characters on the source code representation of that expression. This is crucial to understanding the differences between the examples that are confusing you.

You always need the "top level expression" of the function body to be **exactly** something directly applied to the last argument of the function. You also need for that argument not to be referenced anywhere else, but it otherwise doesn't matter what the "something" is; it could be a complicated expression with many sub parts.

Now let's consider your examples in that light.

```
-- This can be made pointfree quite easily:
let lengths x = map length x
```

Okay, `x` is textually at the end. But is it the argument of a top level application? We've got three parts to this expression, not just two, so our rule doesn't necessarily apply immediately. But remembering that function application is left associative (`f x y` means `f` is applied to x, and the result of that `f x` is applied to `y`), this is `map length` applied to `x`. So we can apply eta reduction to eliminate `x`, leaving just the expression that was applied to it: `map length`.

```
-- However this cannot:
let lengthz x = length `map` x
```

Again `x` is textually last, but we clearly can't just cut it out textually, since that doesn't even result in well-formed code. An infix operator needs a left and a right argument (a name written in backticks like `` `map` `` turns it into an infix operator).

But remember what infix operator syntax *means*. `` length `map` x `` is `map` applied to `length`, and the result of that `map length` applied to `x`. So eta reduction *does* apply, and we can eliminate `x`. But not just by blinding deleting the source code text "x". What is left should be the expression that was applied to `x`, which is `map length` again, not the meaningless source code text `` length `map` ``.

We do have another option with infix operators though. You *can* "leave out" an argument from an infix operator if you convert it to a *section* by wrapping the thing in parentheses. So we could write `map` applied to `length` and not apply the result to a second argument by writing `` (length `map`) ``, if you want to keep the result *looking* similar to what you started with. This also gives another way of eliminating arguments to get to point free code: we can leave out the *first* argument of an infix operator just as easily as the second. For example if we had:

```
f x = x / 3
```

This is `(/)` applied to `x`, and then the result of that applied to `3`. So the argument of the outermost application is `3`, not `x`, and we can't apply eta reduction. But we *can* apply a very similar process because of Haskell's operator section syntax<sup>2</sup>, and eliminate `x` to leave `(/ 3)`. Again, note that the important thing to consider is the *structure* of the expression `x / 3`, not the order of the bits of source code text we use to write it down.

Enough of that digression. Your last example is a little more complicated:

```
agreeLen :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
agreeLen x y = length $ takeWhile id $ zipWith (==) x y
```

`y` (and then `x` if we could do this twice) is at the end of the source code text. But it is **not** the argument of the top-level function application in this expression.

One quirk of Haskell's syntax is that if there are operators involved in an expression (unless they're inside a parenthesised sub-expression), one of them is *always* the top-level application. This is because normal function application is higher-precedence than any possible operator, and it's the **lowest** precedence thing that ends up being the top-level expression. So just from the presence of the `$` operators it's immediately obvious that one of them has to be the "top" function, and there's no way either of them could be applied to just `y` on its own. So eta reduction isn't going to apply immediately.

In more detail, this is `$` applied to `length`, and then to everything on the right. The top-level application is therefore `($) length` being applied to `takeWhile id $ zipWith (==) x y`; `y` is deep inside the argument expression, we need the argument of the top-level application to just be simply `y`.

But remember that `f $ x` is just another way of writing `f x`, usually used only so we don't have to put parentheses around `f` or `x` if those are complex expressions. If we put the parentheses back we get closer to having `y` at the top level.

```
agreeLen x y = length (takeWhile id (zipWith (==) x y))
```

We're still not there. But this is "`length` applied to (`takeWhile id` applied to (`zipWith (==) x` applied to `y`)). This pattern of "chaining" things applied to the result of other applications is exactly what function *composition* with the `.` operator is for. We can mentally reframe this as "`length` applied after `takeWhile id` applied after `zipWith (==) x`, and the whole of that chain applied to `y`". Written in code as:

```
agreeLen x y = (length . takeWhile id . zipWith (==) x) y
```

**Now** we've got `<something>` applied to `y`! So we can eta-reduce:

```
agreeLen x = length . takeWhile id . zipWith (==) x
```

Note that `x`, although now textually last, does *not* fit the same pattern as `y` did above. We don't have parentheses around the whole "function-pipeline" before it's applied to `x`, rather `x` is **part of** the last stage in the pipeline. We *can* shuffle things around to eventually get:

```
agreeLen x = (((length . takeWhile id) .) . zipWith (==)) x
```

and then eta reduce to eliminate `x`, as shown in other answers. But the steps are more complicated; I don't even know what they are, I just copied that expression from @chepner's answer (who copied it from http://pointfree.io). This shows a key difference between the role of `x` and `y` in the original `agreeLen`, even though they both appeared at the end of source code in the right order.

Which just re-emphasises my point: to understand why you can sometimes eta reduce and sometimes not you need to not think of eta reduction as a simple textual rule; you *do* actually have to read and understand the structure of the expressions you're trying to rewrite.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually in pure lambda calculus you can apply this almost as a blind textual rule; Haskell adds more complicated syntax like infix operators with implicit parentheses via precedence/associative, constructs like case, if/then/else, etc.

<sup>2</sup> Infix operator syntax doesn't exist in pure lambda calculus, let alone operator sections. So there's no fancy Greek-letter name for this one, but that's only because the theoreticians who named these rules originally weren't studying Haskell.

Comment: Well, the next step is `agreeLen x = (.) (length . takeWhile id) (zipWith (==) x)`. Now you can write that as `agreeLen = (.) (length . takeWhile id) . zipWith (==)`. Finally, you can bring back the operator section to achieve the desired form.

Answer (score 3):

You can always convert a typed lambda expression into a typed combinator expression, using only the polymorphic S (`<*>`) and K (`const`) combinators. [A Note on Typed Combinators and Typed Lambda Terms](http://www.emis.de/journals/NSJOM/Papers/23_1/NSJOM_23_1_319_329.pdf) shows a proof, which is also an *abstraction algorithm* to convert lambda terms into (point-free) combinator terms:

> 1. |x<sub>α</sub>| x<sub>α</sub> = I<sub>α → α</sub>
> 2. |x<sub>α</sub>| X<sub>α</sub> = K<sub>β → (α → β)</sub>X<sub>β</sub> if x<sub>α</sub> ∉ X<sub>β</sub>
> 3. |x<sub>α</sub>| X<sub>α → β</sub> = X<sub>α → β</sub> if x<sub>α</sub> ∉ X<sub>α → β</sub>
> 4. |x<sub>α</sub>| X<sub>β → γ</sub>Y<sub>β</sub> = S<sub>α → (β → γ) → α → β → (α → γ)</sub>(|x<sub>α</sub>| X<sub>β → γ</sub>)(|x<sub>α</sub>| Y<sub>β</sub>) otherwise

This can be converted into Haskell notation easily:

```
(\(x :: a) -> (x :: a)) = id

-- If X does not mention x
(\(x :: a) -> (X :: a)) = const X

-- If X does not mention x
(\(x :: a) -> (X :: a -> b)) = X

(\(x :: a) -> (X :: b -> c) (Y :: b))
  = (\(x :: a) -> X) <*> (\(x :: a) -> Y)
```

Therefore you can always write a point-free definition, but it might be much larger and uglier without higher-level combinators, and you may need to introduce newtype wrapping & unwrapping or `RankNTypes` to deal with impredicative polymorphism arising from passing polymorphic functions around.

However, in real Haskell code you mainly want to use point-free style when you can “get the arguments to the end of the definition”, that is, when you can eta-reduce `f x = g x` into `f = g`. This works best if you have a simple “pipeline” of functions where you pass one intermediate value along without duplicating or dropping it. For example, here’s a histogram function:

```
-- import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
(f &&& g) x = (f x, g x)

-- import Control.Category ((>>>))
(f >>> g) = g . f

histogram :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
histogram
  = sort                             -- [Char]
  >>> group                          -- [[Char]]
  >>> map (head &&& length)          -- [(Char, Int)]
  >>> sortBy (flip (comparing snd))
```

Comment: Damn, you were faster than me :)

Answer (score 3):

If we call this form of a function definition *point-free*

```
f = e
```

where `f` is just a function name and *e* is an expression,
we can make at least those functions point-free that

1. have a right hand side that is just a function application.
2. don't require pattern matching on their arguments and
3. the arguments are not mentioned in "complex" subexpressions, such as list comprehensions, case, let or lambda abstractions.

That is, if the arguments are just simple names, we can make it point-free if the other two conditions are also met.

For arguments that need some pattern matching, if we can eliminate the constructor with some function (like `maybe`, `either`, `fst`, `snd`) we can often rewrite the function so that we get one that can be written point-free:

```
 f (a,b) = (b,a)
 f' ab   = (snd ab, fst ab)
 f'' = (pure (,) <*> snd) <*> fst
```

Also, an `if` expressions on the right hand side can be rewritten as application of `bool`

Here is an algorithm that eliminates some variable *v* from an expression *e* such that the resulting expression *x* doesn't contain *v* and, when applied to *v* is equivalent to *e*

- If *e* doesn't contain *v*, the result is `pure e`
- If *e* is *v*, the result is `id`
- If *e* is some expression *f* applied to *v* and *f* does not mention *v* the result is *f*
- Otherwise, *e* must be an application *g h* where at least one of *g* and *h* mentions *v*. The result would be *g' <*> h'* where *g'* is the expression that results when eliminating *v* from *g* and *h'* is the expression that results when eliminating *v* from *h*

And here is how to make a function definition point-free that fulfills the requirements outlined above

```
 f v1 v2 v3 ... vn = e
```

- let *e'* be the elimination of *vn* from *e*
- Write down the new function

  f' v1 v2 v3 ... v(n-1) = e'
- If no arguments are left, you're done
- Otherwise, make *f'* point-free

Note, there are different ways to eliminate a variable form an expression using functions like `(.)` `flip` etc. that often leads to shorter code, however, the above is the most basic method since it only needs the S, K and I combinators (which are written `<*>` `pure` and `id` in Haskell).