# Can this function be written in point-free style? If not, why?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

One related question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917772/what-are-the-prerequisites-for-a-point-free-function-in-haskell), but some of the answer say that almost anything can be made point free, so what is wrong with this function?

```hs
\[x] -> x
```

http://pointfree.io/ doesn't seem to be able to write it in point-free style. Does this mean that it cannot be written that way? If so, what is the theoretical reason for it?

I can only observe that the function above is a "crippled" version of `head` (or `last`, fwiw) which can only operate on singleton lists. Indeed, applied on non singleton lists, it errors this way in `ghci`:

```
*** Exception: <interactive>:380:5-13: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda
```

Maybe the "non-exhaustivity" on the pattern is the reason why some functions cannot be written in point-free style?

**Edit in the light of the answers:**

I did not expect that the answers to my question could be so complex (I feel I just thought that the short answer was *no, it cannot*, actually), so I need to find some time to read them carefully, experiment a bit, and wrap my mind around them, otherwise I cannot decide which one should be accepted. For the time being, +1 to Jon Purdy's answer, which I could easily understand up to *This is where I would stop in ordinary code*.

Comment: `head` will basically unwrap the element, but it will not raise an error for lists with two or more elements.

Comment: `only` will normally do the trick: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-8.10.1/docs/Util.html#v:only but this is equivalent to `head` in non-debug mode as a performance hack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, pretty much anything *can* be made pointfree. The tricky thing is what functions you'll allow in the resulting expression. If we pattern match, we generally need a fold function to do the matching instead. So, for instance, if we pattern matched on a `Maybe a`, we'd need to replace that with [`maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe). Similarly, `Either a b` patterns can be written in terms of [`either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:either).

Note the pattern in the signatures

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a

maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> (Maybe a -> b)
```

`Maybe a` has two constructors, one which takes no arguments and the other which takes an `a`. So `maybe` takes two arguments: one which is a 0-ary function (`b`), and one which takes an `a` (`a -> b`), and then returns a function from `Maybe a -> b`. The same pattern is present in `either`

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b

either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> (Either a b -> c)
```

Two cases. The first takes an `a` and produces whatever `c` we want. The second takes a `b` and produces whatever `c` we want. In every case, we want one function for each possible term in the sum type.

In order to systematically pointfree a function like `\[x] -> x`, we'd need a similar fold. `[a]` is declared as, essentially

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

So we'd need a function with this signature

```
list :: b -> (a -> [a] -> b) -> ([a] -> b)
```

Now, `flip foldr` comes close

```
flip foldr :: b -> (a -> b -> b) -> ([a] -> b)
```

But it's recursive. It calls its provided function on the `[a]` part of `a : [a]`. We want a true fold, which isn't provided by Haskell's base libraries. A quick Hoogle search tells us that this function does exist in a package though, called [`extra`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.3/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:list). Of course, for this small example we can just write it ourselves very easily.

```
list :: b -> (a -> [a] -> b) -> ([a] -> b)
list f g x = case x of
               [] -> f
               (y:ys) -> g y ys
```

Now we can apply it to your `\[x] -> x` easily. First, let's write what your function really does, including all of the messy `undefined` cases (I'll use `undefined` rather than a long error message here, for brevity)

```
func :: [a] -> a
func x = case x of
           [] -> undefined
           (y:ys) -> case ys of
                       [] -> y
                       (_:_) -> undefined
```

Now every case statement exactly matches each constructor once. This is ripe for transformation into a fold.

```
func :: [a] -> a
func x = case x of
         [] -> undefined
         (y:ys) -> list y undefined ys
```

And now we transform the outer case as well

```
func :: [a] -> a
func x = list undefined (\y -> list y undefined) x
```

So we have

```
func :: [a] -> a
func = list undefined (\y -> list y undefined)
```

Or, if we want to be truly crazy about it

```
func :: [a] -> a
func = list undefined (flip list undefined)
```

## But this function isn't in base

Yeah, that's true. We kind of cheated by using a fold that didn't exist. If we want to do it systematically, we need that fold operator. But without it, we can still kludge it together with `foldr1`, which suffices for our particular purposes.

```
func' :: [a] -> a
func' = foldr1 (const (const undefined))
```

So, to answer your question, we can't always systematically replace pattern matching like in your example with pointfree, *unless* we have a fold function with the right signature. Fortunately, that function can always be written, for any Haskell 98 data type (possibly GADTs as well, but I haven't considered that possibility in any depth). But even without that support, we can still make it work, kind of.

Comment: +1, I found time to read you answer only now; it took a bit for me to get past the part where you change a `case` to `list`, as there was a typo, which I've just fixed.

Comment: About the easiest part of the answer, the final part, so `func'` folds the input list by starting with its first element as the accumulator, but if fails as soon as the binary function `const . const undefined` is applied since that function ignores the two arguments and gives back `undefined`. Very nice!

Comment: It seems pretty clear that `maybe` is like a fold function, as it takes an accumulator and a function to apply to what's inside the `Maybe`. However it is not easy to look at `either` in the same way. And in any case this seem like a more generalized fold than an actual fold, as we are not folding a `Foldable`, right? Do you know some good place where I can find more about this interesting views (which look a lot like lovely theoretical stuff to me)? Well, HTNW seems to refer exactly to this stuff to, in the beginning of his answer.

Comment: You might be interested in answering to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251843/changing-a-do-expression-that-uses-pattern-matching-to-application-of-the-bind-o) I asked.

Comment: You're right about that. Whereas the `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad` sequence in Haskell are strictly based on the corresponding mathematical concepts, `Foldable` is more of a loose, pragmatic typeclass that doesn't really have an exact corresponding mathematical definition. The notion of "fold" I'm using here is what mathematicians would call a catamorphism to an F-algebra. You supply `either` with an F-algebra (where F=`Either`) and it produces the unique catamorphism into your algebra.

Comment: Wikipedia has all the formal definitions of these terms, but when I was first learning a lot of this stuff, this paper (https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91m.pdf) was invaluable for understanding the pragmatic side of things. And the concepts in that paper have been implemented in a Haskell library (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) that, while impractically verbose for real-world projects, is handy for educational use.

Answer (score 19):

Well, a data type isn't a function. As long as your function isn't unwrapping any data values (i.e. it's just shuffling them between functions/constructors), you can write it point free, but there's simply no syntax for point free matching. However, you only ever need one non-point-free function per data type: the fold. In Haskell, data types are pretty much *defined* by their folds. Taking the folds of the relevant data types as primitives, you can rewrite any function point free. Note that there are actually several possible "folds". For `[a]`, the recursive one (which comes from the Church/Böhm-Berarducci encoding) is `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. Another possible fold is the "`case`-but-it's-a-function" one, `(a -> [a] -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, which comes from the Scott encoding (recursion can then be recovered with `fix`, which is another "pointful pointfree primitive"), but, as @SilvioMayolo notes, there isn't such a function in the standard library. Either would do, but we don't have the latter predefined so let's just use `foldr`.

```
\[x] -> x
```

can be written

```
fst . foldr (\x f -> (snd f x, \_ -> error "got (_ : _ : _) wanted [x]")) (error "got [] wanted [x]", id)
-- I don't care enough to replicate the exact exceptions.
-- this is "flattened" from
let fold [] = (error "got [] wanted [x]", id)
    fold (x : xs) = (snd (fold xs) x, \_ -> error "got (_ : _ : _) wanted [x]")
in  fst . fold
```

`fold` returns a pair, basically `(what to return if this was the entire list, how to transform the head if it wasn't)`. For `[]`, we want to return an error if that was the entire list, but otherwise pass through the element right before we hit `[]`. For `x : xs`, if there is an element preceding it, we want to ignore it and return an error, and if there isn't, we want to pass it to `snd (fold xs)`, which checks if `xs = []` or else gives an error. We've eliminated all matches, so just shove this through pointfree.io to get the `\x f -> _` in the argument to `foldr` out:

```
behead = fst . foldr (flip flip (const (error "got (_ : _ : _) wanted [x]")) . ((,) .) . flip snd) (error "got [] wanted [x]", id)
ghci> :t behead
behead :: Foldable t => t c -> c
ghci> behead []
*** Exception: got [] wanted [x]
ghci> behead [1]
1
ghci> behead [1, 2]
*** Exception: got (_ : _ : _) wanted [x]
ghci> behead [1..]
*** Exception: got (_ : _ : _) wanted [x]
```

Lovely.

Note: a previous version of this answer used an "inlined" auxiliary data type, basically because it just "came to me" as I was writing it. However, it failed to handle infinite lists properly (`behead [1..]` would hang). This version uses the built in pairs as the auxiliary data type, which have sufficient library support that I don't have to inline them to make it pointfree. It is slightly harder to inline `(,)`, thereby eliminating the pointfullness inside the implementations of `fst` and `snd`, but it is still possible, using this newtype:

```
newtype Pair a b = Pair { unPair :: forall r. (a -> b -> r) -> r }
```

Alternatively, cheat on the types a bit and use this:

```
-- residual pointfullness can be reduced by pointfree.io
\xs -> foldr (\x r f -> f (r (const id) x) (\_ -> error "got (_ : _ : _) wanted [x]")) (\f -> f (error "got [] wanted [x]") id) xs (\x _ _ -> x) undefined
```

Comment: I love your function name!

Comment: It might feel less pointy if you use `first` or `second` rather than `snd`. I'm guessing you can do so.

Comment: @dfeuer The `fst` here isn't going anywhere, modifying both elements is a little annoying (I suppose `***` would work), and they're still pointy on the inside.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to write this in pointfree form is to use a fold, where the accumulator state is one of the following:

- **Empty**: We haven’t seen an element yet; keep it
- **Full**: We have seen an element; raise an error

If the final state is **Empty**, we also raise an error. This accumulator can be represented naturally with `Maybe`:

```
fromSingleton :: (Foldable t) => t a -> a
fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe (error "empty list")
  . foldr (flip maybe (error "plural list") . Just) Nothing
```

This is where I would stop in ordinary code. But…

If you don’t want to use an auxiliary data type, you can get rid of the `Maybe` by representing it with Böhm–Berarducci encoding:

```
type Maybe' r a
  = r          -- ‘Nothing’ continuation
  -> (a -> r)  -- ‘Just’ continuation
  -> r         -- Result

just' :: a -> Maybe' r a
-- just' = \ x _n j -> j x
just'
  = const     -- Ignore ‘Nothing’ continuation
  . flip ($)  -- Apply ‘Just’ continuation to value

nothing' :: Maybe' r a
-- nothing' = \ n _j -> n
nothing' = const  -- Ignore ‘Just’ continuation

maybe' :: r -> (a -> r) -> Maybe' r a -> r
-- maybe' = \ n j k -> k n j
maybe'
  = flip      -- Apply to ‘Just’ continuation
  . flip ($)  -- Apply to ‘Nothing’ continuation

fromMaybe' :: r -> Maybe' r r -> r
-- fromMaybe' = \ n k -> k n id
fromMaybe' = flip maybe' id  -- Pass ‘id’ as ‘Just’ continuation
```

However, we can’t just do a wholesale replacement of `Just` with `just'`, `maybe` with `maybe'`, and so on; the types won’t work out:

```
> :t fromMaybe' (error "empty list") . foldr (flip maybe' (error "plural list") . just') nothing'

<interactive>:…:…: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: c ~ Maybe' c c
      Expected type: c -> Maybe' c c -> Maybe' c c
        Actual type: c -> Maybe' (Maybe' c c) c -> Maybe' c c
    • In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely
        ‘(flip maybe' (error "plural list") . just')’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
        ‘foldr (flip maybe' (error "plural list") . just') nothing'’
      In the expression:
        fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
          . foldr (flip maybe' (error "plural list") . just') nothing'
```

The problem is that we’re returning a `Maybe'` from a `Maybe'` continuation, and the compiler is trying to *unify* the two result types. One solution is to first eta-expand to let the typechecker know where we want to construct a distinct function:

```
> :t fromMaybe' (error "empty list") . foldr (\ x acc -> \ n j -> maybe' (just' x n j) (error "plural list") acc) nothing'

fromMaybe' (error "empty list") . foldr (\ x acc -> \ n j -> maybe' (just' x n j) (error "plural list") acc) nothing'
  :: Foldable t => t c -> c
```

Then we can incrementally rewrite to pointfree form:

```
fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (\ x acc
      -> \ n j
        -> maybe'
          (just' x n j)
          (error "plural list")
          acc)
    nothing'

-- Move ‘n’ & ‘j’ past ‘error …’ with ‘flip’:

fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (\ x acc
      -> \ n j
        -> flip maybe'
           ----
          (error "plural list")
          (just' x n j)
          acc)
    nothing'

-- Move ‘n’ & ‘j’ past ‘acc’ with ‘flip’ again:

fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (\ x acc
      -> \ n j
        -> flip (flip maybe' (error "plural list")) acc
           ----
          (just' x n j))
    nothing'

-- Eta-reduce ‘j’ with composition:

fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (\ x acc
      -> \ n
        -> flip (flip maybe' (error "plural list")) acc
          . just' x n)
          --
    nothing'

-- Eta-reduce ‘n’ with ‘fmap’ (to map “under” an argument):

fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (\ x acc
      -> fmap (flip (flip maybe' (error "plural list")) acc)
         ----
        . just' x)
    nothing'

-- Move ‘x’ rightward with ‘flip’ on the outside:

fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (flip (\ acc x
     ----
      -> fmap (flip (flip maybe' (error "plural list")) acc)
        . just' x))
    nothing'

-- Replace composition with ‘fmap’:

fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (flip (\ acc x
      -> fmap (fmap (flip (flip maybe' (error "plural list")) acc))
         ----
        (just' x)))
    nothing'

-- Eta-reduce ‘x’ with composition:

fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (flip (\ acc
      -> fmap (fmap (flip (flip maybe' (error "plural list")) acc))
        . just'))
        --
    nothing'

-- Replace composition with ‘fmap’:

fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (flip (\ acc
      -> fmap (fmap (fmap (flip (flip maybe' (error "plural list")) acc)))
         ----
        just'))
    nothing'

-- Move ‘acc’ rightward with ‘flip’:

fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (flip (\ acc
      -> flip fmap just'
         ----
        (fmap (fmap (flip (flip maybe' (error "plural list")) acc)))))
    nothing'

-- Eta-reduce with composition:

fromSingleton
  = fromMaybe' (error "empty list")
  . foldr
    (flip
      (flip fmap just'
        . fmap . fmap . flip (flip maybe' (error "plural list"))))
        --     -      -
    nothing'
```

This is fully pointfree as well (far less readable than our original code, but better than what `pointfree` generates). In fact it’s good practice in pointfree code to use many small auxiliary definitions like `fromMaybe'` instead of inlining everything, but we can proceed to inline their definitions.

However, you *can’t* inline them naïvely and get exactly the same type—if you do, you’ll arrive at `(Foldable t) => t (a -> b) -> a -> b`. It could be a good exercise to work through where you need to eta-expand and rewrite in order to obtain the expected type, `(Foldable t) => t a -> a`.